# Display dynamic menu in mvc layout page

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

i want to display dynamic menu in mvc layout page.
in my database table has menuid and parentid from that i want to display nested menus.
if anyone have solution please help me and if any other method for this give an example.
here is my database 
[Database Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLU3a.png)
here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (MachineShopDBEntities db = new MachineShopDBEntities())
        {
            List<MenuMaster> list = db.MenuMasters.ToList();
            ViewBag.MenuList = new SelectList(list);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

here is my model

```
public partial class MenuMaster
{
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public string MenuText { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public List<MenuMaster> menus { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> users { get; set; }
}
```

here is my view

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
                @{
                    if (ViewBag.MenuList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var items in ViewBag.MenuList.Items)
                        {
                            string action = items.ActionName;
                            string controller = items.ControllerName;
                            <li class="treeview">
                                @if (items.ParentID == items.MenuID)
                                {
                                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                        <li class="treeview">
                                            <a href="/@items.ControllerName/@items.ActionName">
                                                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> <span>@items.MenuText</span>
                                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                }

                                <a href="/@items.ControllerName/@items.ActionName">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>@items.MenuText</span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        }
                    }
                }
```

this type of output i want 
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fiaK.png)

Comment: Is above code gives any problem or error? or not work as intended?

Comment: no error in output but. how to display child and subchild and its subchild.?

Comment: ok let me prepare answer for you

Comment: okay. thank you ..

Comment: you want drop-down menu or tree view like menu?

Comment: i want drop-down menu

Comment: i share image.. what i exactly want . display menu in side bar as dropdown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a one **Recursive** method that can run even if you have Nth submenus

**1) Tree View Sidebar-Menu**

Add below method in your razor view (_Layout.cshtml)

```
@helper GetTreeMenus(IEnumerable<WebApplicationMVC.Models.MenuMaster> siteMenu, Nullable<int> parentID)
{
    foreach (var i in siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentId.Equals(parentID)))
    {
        var submenu = siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentId.Equals(i.MenuId)).Count();

        string action = i.ActionName;
        string controller = i.ControllerName;

        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/@i.ControllerName/@i.ActionName">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> <span>@i.MenuText</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            @GetTreeMenus(siteMenu, i.MenuId)
        </ul>
    }
}
```

And call this method with below code in same razor (_Layout.cshtml)

```
  @{
    if (Session["MenuList"] != null)
    {
        <div class="sidebar-menu">

            @GetTreeMenus(Session["MenuList"] as IEnumerable<WebApplicationMVC.Models.MenuMaster>, 0)

        </div>
    }
}
```

And action method like.

Below `Index` action method in `Home` controller will be in your `Default` route in `RouteConfig.cs`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (MenuMaster db = new MenuMaster())
    {
        List<MenuMaster> list = db.MyMenus().ToList();
        Session["MenuList"] = list;
    }
    return View();
}
```

**For this example i used test data like**

```
public List<MenuMaster> MyMenus()
{
    return new List<MenuMaster> {
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =1, MenuText="Home", ParentId = 0, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =2, MenuText="Sales", ParentId = 0, ControllerName="Sales", ActionName = "Sales" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =3, MenuText="Report", ParentId = 0, ControllerName="Report", ActionName = "Report" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =4, MenuText="About Us", ParentId = 1, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =5, MenuText="Company Profile", ParentId = 1, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =6, MenuText="Add Invoice", ParentId = 2, ControllerName="Sale", ActionName = "Sale" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =7, MenuText="Update Invice", ParentId = 2, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =8, MenuText="Delete Invoice", ParentId = 2, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =9, MenuText="Daily Report", ParentId = 3, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =10, MenuText="Monthly Report", ParentId = 3, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =11, MenuText="Update Invice 1", ParentId = 7, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    new MenuMaster { MenuId  =12, MenuText="Update Invice 2", ParentId = 11, ControllerName="Home", ActionName = "Index" },
    };
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @Niharika Jagani, view the answer might be it help you :)  modify `html` and `css` with your need

Comment: @NiharikaJagani, just replace `<ul class="sidebar-menu">` with `<div class="sidebar-menu">` and closing tag also from `</ul>` to `</div>` for well dom document tree, Its just suggestion, you may see in answer :)

Comment: yes we just use "<li class="treeview">" instead of  <ul class="treeview-menu"> and after that we add ancher tag and then after we write <ul class="treeview-menu"> <li class="treeview"> for our tree view structure and after ew put @GetTreeMenus(siteMenu, i.MenuID) method instead of after <li>... but this changes is minor for our structure ...your answer is work for me ...thank u again @ershoaib

Comment: glad to hear that answer help you and you got what you want :)

Comment: yes one problem is that when redirect page menu will disable because of ViewBag..but i solve that by using session

Comment: thanks for your comment i also make changes like so :)