# Loading a menu structure on every razor page in asp .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

After user authentication I'm supposed to change the user menu based on the roles of the user.

To do this, I created a service which fetched the menu the user is expected to see:

```cs
        public List<MenuStructure> LoadCompleteMenuRole(string role)
        {
            List<MenuStructure> resultList = null;

            var menuHeaders = LoadMenuHeadersForTheGivenRole(role);

            if (menuHeaders != null && menuHeaders.Count > 0)
            {
                resultList = new List<MenuStructure>();

                foreach (var menuHeader in menuHeaders)
                {
                    var menuStructure = new MenuStructure
                    {
                        MenuName = menuHeader.HeaderName,
                        Caption = menuHeader.Caption
                    };

                    var menuDetails = LoadMenuDetailsForTheGivenHeader(menuHeader.Id);

                    if (menuDetails != null && menuDetails.Count > 0)
                    {
                        menuStructure.MenuElements = new List<MenuElement>();

                        foreach (var menuDetail in menuDetails)
                        {
                            var menuElement = new MenuElement
                            {
                                ElementName = menuDetail.DetailName,
                                ElementCaption = menuDetail.Caption,
                                Destination = menuDetail.Destination
                            };

                            menuStructure.MenuElements.Add(menuElement);
                        }
                    }

                    resultList.Add(menuStructure);
                }
            }

            return resultList;
        }
```

My problem? Where do I implement the service so the menus get loaded in every razor page I create?

Comment: You should use a view component and include it your layout.

Comment: as @Roar S said, using a view component and load menu list by recursive method. Here is a similar [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51878638/13655939).